# Divergence theorem to find flux through only part of a region

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-differential-equations, divergence-theorem

Use the divergence theorem to compute flux integral $ \iint SF⋅dS$, where  $F(x,y,z)=yj−zk $ and $S$ consists of the union of paraboloid $ y=x^2+z^2,0≤y≤1$,  and disk $ x^2+z^2≤1,y=1$,  oriented outward. What is the flux through just the paraboloid?

Here's what I have so far: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X5SuN.jpg)

The answer key says it's $-\pi$ whereas I am getting $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

If $\vec{F}(x,y,z)=\langle0,y,-z\rangle$
then $\nabla _{\{x,y,z\}}\cdot \vec{F}(x,y,z)=0$

Hence, the total flux is 0. We must use the surface integral.

$$\vec{r}=\langle x,x^2+z^2,z \rangle$$

$$\vec{\delta_x}= \delta_x \cdot \vec{r} = \langle 1, 2x, 0 \rangle$$
$$\vec{\delta_z}= \delta_z \cdot \vec{r} = \langle 0, 2z, 1 \rangle$$

The normal vector for the paraboloid:
$$\vec{N}=\vec{\delta_x}\times \vec{\delta_z}=\langle 2x,-1,2z\rangle$$

Integrand for the surface integral:
$$\vec{F}(x,y,z)\cdot\vec{N}=-y-2 z^2|_{y=x^2+z^2}=-x^2 - 3 z^2$$

$$\int _{-1}^1\int _{-\sqrt{1-x^2}}^{\sqrt{1-x^2}}\left(-x^2-3 z^2\right)dzdx=\int_{-1}^1 \left(-2 \left(1-x^2\right)^{3/2}-2 x^2 \sqrt{1-x^2}\right) \, dx=-\pi$$